# How to share visual studio boomarks between developers?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, bookmarks

I've recently stumbled across the ability to use boomarks in Visual Studio. (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42973/Using-Bookmark-in-Visual-Studio.aspx)

As far as I've googled, I've found out that the bookmarks are stored in the .suo file of the project, that holds userspecific information is that therefore not stored in sourcecontrol.

I'm guessing maybe someone found a way around it or created an addin for this purpose. So how can I share bookmarks between developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bookmarks are poorly supported in Visual Studio extensibility interfaces.  There is no way to enumerate them.  Only Clear/Set/Next/PreviousBookmark methods are available.  Not good enough to do what you want to do.